# Error when connecting to Snowflake REST request for URL failed

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am receiving the below error when trying to establish connection to Snowflake. I am working on to load data from the SQL server tables to Snowflake tables via SSIS. I have set up the ODBC connection and connecting through a proxy, entered the proxy name in the DSN. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Error: REST request for URL https:.//abc.azure.snowflakecomputing.com failed : CURL error (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=56 msg = 'Failure when receiving data from the peer"'

(renamed actual account name to abc for security purposes)

Comment: hey, having the same issue here. were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the JDBC driver not being able to be found in the JAVA classpath.
There are two ways of pointing to the location of the JDBC jars

1. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-install.html#label-spark-cluster-setup
2. Create a JAVA_CLASSPATH variable and update the locations of the spark jars and JDBC jars.

Comment: I am using Snowflake ODBC drivers to connect, not JDBC.